# Comparing elements of the same multi dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I do have an multi dimensional array in this format:

```
Cjk = [[81 51 31] [82 47 54] [34 55 64] [96 73 43]];
```

How can I get the minimum values on each index of the arrays contained.

I want this output:

```
34 47 31  # these are the minimum values compared to each one values of the same index
```

I have tried some methods but they were unsucesfully because I had to work with I and J because the array Cjk will get more values in time so it needs to be scalable

Comment: `[min(x) for x in zip(*Cjk)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the minimum in each column. You can use `zip` here.

```
Cjk = [[81 51 31] [82 47 54] [34 55 64] [96 73 43]]
min_cols=[min(lst) for lst in zip(*Cjk)]
# [34, 47, 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
In [21]: list(map(lambda x:min(x),zip(*Cjk)))
Out[21]: [34, 47, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import numpy and find minimums and maximums inrows and columns of the matrix, using axis parameter.
Like in this example:

```
import numpy as np

>>> x = -np.matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))); x

matrix([[  0,  -1,  -2,  -3],
        [ -4,  -5,  -6,  -7],
        [ -8,  -9, -10, -11]])

>>> x.min()

-11
>>> x.min(0)

matrix([[ -8,  -9, -10, -11]])

>>> x.min(1)
matrix([[ -3],
        [ -7],
        [-11]])
```

Check this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.min.html